# Django ManyToManyField Approve Add

Tags: django

In our app I have a lot of ManyToManyFields, for which some need the add or remove action to be approved by a supervisor. At the moment we solve this by adding another Model, and when this model gets approved, the Field is added to the ManyToMany Field.

I find this quite stupid to be honest, that I am doing the same work for every ManyToManyField and thought there might be a better solution for this. I played around with Django-FSM already and this is exactly what I need in our app, but it only works for a status field and not for doing something like described above.

Does anybody has an idea on how to improve this process?

Comment: Why not: there are two states here: not-approved, and approved.

Comment: Currently it is hard to tell, since there is not much context. Is it hard to simply construct an `Action` table, and that table has a single m2m relation?